# Django static files not serving when running inside Docker container

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, docker, dockerfile

I have a django application thats is rendering the static files when run outside docker container. I added a Dockerfile so that I can run it in a container. However, the static files are not getting served when running in the container

The sample app that I have used can be found [here](https://github.com/LinkedInLearning/learning-django-2825501/tree/final)

I have added the following Dockerfile at the root level

```
FROM python:3.8

#add project files to the usr/src/app folder
ADD . /usr/src/app

#set directoty where CMD will execute 
WORKDIR /usr/src/app/wisdompets
COPY requirements.txt ./

# Get pip to download and install requirements:
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

# Expose ports
EXPOSE 8000

# default command to execute    
CMD exec gunicorn wisdompets.wsgi:application --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 --workers 3
```

And the requirements.txt file at root level as below

```
django==3.0.3
gunicorn==20.0.4
```

The static files settings in my settings.py is as follows

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
]
```

Please let me know if there's something wrong with my configuration

Answer (score 0):

You are missing `collectstatic` command which will package static files alongside the app.

Check [this link](http://michal.karzynski.pl/blog/2015/04/19/packaging-django-applications-as-docker-container-images/) for reference.

Comment: Where did you add it? If you are running it before creating a Docker container, did you create `volume` for sharing static files from your file system to the container?

Comment: I followed the link you gave. They are doing that in the docker entrypoint script which is invoked when the container is started

Answer (score 0):

Revisa keeps you configured.

```
STATIC_ROOT
```

You should have no problems when you run the command.

```
python manage.py \
        collectstatic \
        --verbosity 0 \
        --noinput \
        --clear
```

If it's fine but still doesn't render the statics.
Check the `gunicorn` documentation.

I recommend you to use `uwsgi` is much more elegant.
https://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/